# Tailwind CSS bigger screens overwrites lower screens on Mobile size

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

So I have this issue where the custom 2lg: / lg: screens overwrites the md: screen even when the react app screen is correct to the md: screen. Look the screenshot for the issue in "inspect". [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TpFl.png)

My React app have Tailwind CSS & Typescript.

Here you also have my `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
                sans: ["Lato", "sans-serif"],
            },
      screens: {
        '2xl': {'max': '1535px'},
        'xl': {'max': '1279px'},
        '2lg': {'max': '1118px'},
        'lg': {'max': '1023px'},
        '2md': {'max': '873px'},
        'md': {'max': '767px'},
        'sm': {'max': '639px'},
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/4.7.4/typescript.js" integrity="sha512-6XXsY/GhEJyCMd6Kj0VBmh0DZIrKqIWNewwC6gI/n7Nt2qnUlepLu8BtRq7OTUvCCXj3a+OTCSLo5PknjxghtA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

**And here is the code of the component.**

```js
interface ProjectProps {
  image: string;
  title: string;
  widthOne ? : boolean;
  widthTwo ? : boolean;
}

const Item = (props: ProjectProps) => {
  return ( <
    div style = {
      {
        backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0, .65), rgba(0,0,0, .65)), url(${props.image})`
      }
    }
    className = {
      `bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-cover md:h-[17rem] 2lg:col-span-2 md:col-span-1 ${
            props.widthOne ? "col-span-4" : ""
            } ${
                props.widthTwo ? "col-span-3" : ""
                }`
    } >
    <
    div className = "w-[60%] h-full flex justify-start items-end pb-10 pl-10 2xl:w-[80%] 2xl:pb-5 2xl:pl-5 md:w-[70%]" >
    <
    h1 className = "font-semibold text-3xl 2lg:text-2xl" > {
      props.title
    } < /h1> <
    /div> <
    /div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/4.7.4/typescript.js" integrity="sha512-6XXsY/GhEJyCMd6Kj0VBmh0DZIrKqIWNewwC6gI/n7Nt2qnUlepLu8BtRq7OTUvCCXj3a+OTCSLo5PknjxghtA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

I have tried to setup Tailwind CSS & TypeScript on a new react-app, this solved the issue once. But now it just continues sadly. What the reason is I can't really solve or explain.

I am using, jQuery, react-helmet, typescript, react-router-dom, body-scroll-lock. I have tried the standard things as well, reinstall npm and remove package-lock.json and so on.

All the help would be appreciated at the moment, this is really disturbing and in a hurry with this project. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#max-width-breakpoints), in your `tailwind.config.js` file, you have to put the `screens` object outside the `extend` object.

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      '2xl': {'max': '1535px'},
      // => @media (max-width: 1535px) { ... }

      'xl': {'max': '1279px'},
      // => @media (max-width: 1279px) { ... }

      'lg': {'max': '1023px'},
      // => @media (max-width: 1023px) { ... }

      'md': {'max': '767px'},
      // => @media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

      'sm': {'max': '639px'},
      // => @media (max-width: 639px) { ... }
    }
  }
}
```